# RStudio can't find LaTeX after Mavericks update

Tags: r, osx-mavericks, rstudio, tex, pdflatex

I have been using Sweave for quite sometime on my system using RStudio. 
However, I recently upgraded my Mac OS from Lion to Mavericks.

This caused several issues:
First, RStudio was not able to locate the R library, and it just wont start. I reinstalled RStudio, but still got the same issue. So I reinstalled both R and RStudio, and then RStudio started to work.

And now, RStudio is still not able to locate TeX installation, and gives me the following warning:
"No TeX installation detected. Please install TeX before compiling."

This will probably get fixed by a reinstall, but I would prefer to avoid a fresh download of [TeX (~2.3G)](http://tug.org/mactex/).

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Your best bet is to do the download (or pull the MacTeX DMG/pkd off of a Time Machine backup) and re-install. Even if you "repair" the install, enough was changed that you might get hit with something missing right when you don't have time to do the re-install. (I had to do this after the update, so I feel your pain)

Comment: The part where RStudio cannot locate the TeX installation just happened to me with upgrade to OS X El Capitan (10.11.3).  Tried installing latest RStudio version (0.99.879) but still have same message.  Downloading latest mactex to see if that will help.

Answer (score 2):

RStudio expects `pdflatex` to be on the system path (i.e. entering `Sys.which("pdflatex")` at the R console should return the path to `pdflatex`).

You can fix the problem by getting `pdflatex` back on the system path:

1. Find the path where `pdflatex` is installed on your system--likely `/usr/texbin`, but use `find /usr -name pdflatex` if you need help.
2. Create a file called `TeX` in `/etc/paths.d` that contains this path.

For example:

```
$ sudo -s "echo /usr/texbin > /etc/paths.d/TeX"
```

You'll need to restart to apply the changes.

Comment: I just went ahead and downloaded the MacTex. Thanks for the answer though!!

Comment: I think mactex installs into `/usr/textbin` and I think that gets wiped out when you upgrade.

Comment: @hadley Indeed.  I couldn't find a `/usr/textbin` folder after upgrade to El Capitan.  The closest I could find were `/bibtex/` and `/tex/` folders in `/Library/TeX/Local/`.    Also `Sys.which("pdflatex")` couldn't find anything.  I found the following PDF from mactex folks which contains some potentially useful info: https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf

Comment: Following commands from pg. 4, section 8 worked for me:  
`cd /Library/TeX`
`sudo ln -s Distributions/Programs/texbin texbin`
`echo "/Library/TeX/texbin" >~/Desktop/TeX`
`sudo cp ~/Desktop/TeX /etc/paths.d/TeX`

"(giving your Admin password when requested) in the Terminal application. You can then delete the TeX file on your Desktop. Note: it’s advisable to copy and paste the commands to Terminal."