# Sweave not working in Rstudio - found path, but how to set?

Tags: rstudio, sweave, tex, pdflatex

I am having the same problem as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229657/rstudio-cant-find-latex-after-mavericks-update).  That is, I am getting a "No TeX" installation detected.  I did reinstall tex after I received the Yosemite-beta OS.  I located the paths to tex at the terminal using the following command:

```
/usr -name pdflatex
```

And, I came up with the following paths.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex
```

I am wondering which path I should use and the specific file to be constructed.  The post I am using as a reference suggests:

```
$ sudo -s "echo /usr/texbin > /etc/paths.d/TeX"
```

I'm not proficient in the terminal, so I am a bit afraid of doing too much at the command line unless I know for sure what I am actually doing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest RStudio 0.98.1079 works for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and I got a solutions that worked for me. Open your terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/texbin/pdflatex /usr/bin/pdflatex
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue after installing the Sierra OS on my Mac, and the solution posted above did not work for me. However, installing the FixLink.pkg (found at the bottom of [this page](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html)) did fix the issue.

Comment: Maybe add into your answer some details on why the above solution did not work? Did the command give an error?